# Заход на сайт через определённые порты только по OpenVPN

Tags: безопасность, vpn, порты, openvpn

На сервере крутится сайт. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы по портам `80` и `443` на сайт можно было зайти только по OpenVPN?

Answer (score 3):

Для этого достаточно изменить настройки веб-сервера - замените видимо указанный сейчас биндинг к ip всех сетевых интерфейсов на биндинг только к ip виртуального сетевого интерфейса OpenVPN.

Ну или тупо запретите запросы с других интерфейсов правилами какого-нибудь файрвола вроде iptables.